# Firefox can't display math in wikipedia.org

Tags: 16.04, firefox, fonts

When I try to open a wikipedia page with equations I see just blank space in their place:

[image]

Although I can see png and image files in other wiki pages.

I checked permissions in *Tool* > *Page Info* and everything is set to Default. In **about:config**, **permissions.default.image** is set to 1.
I've also tried to run Firefox in safe mode with no luck.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox version 46.0.1

Comment: Could you provide a wikipedia link which features such an equation?

Comment: You can try inspecting the element to see the styles applied to those equation sections.

Comment: whatever page with equations, the one in the pic is [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory#Bloch.27s_theorem_and_wavevectors]

Comment: inspecting it is not giving me much info, What I get is:  <img src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ee32d0e6833d75a4fd395028758ef20de73725b2" class="mwe-math-fallback-image-inline" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: -1.005ex; width:22.243ex; height:3.343ex;">

Comment: Search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula for "firefox". See if that helps. BTW, do you have any ad or script blocker active? I can see formulae for the page you linked to just fine in Firefox 47. Can you see https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/da2e77e3472b4b231713b061a11a222e6c77d693 in a new tab?

Comment: Also, do you have any style sheet active?

Comment: And what happens when you run Firefox in safe mode (Alt+Help, Restart with Addons Disabled)?

Comment: same thing, I can't see them in safe mode either. If I right click > View Image, I can see them.

Comment: Same here with Firefox 48 on Xubuntu 16.04. I can see the Image by clicking "View Image". I downloaded the svg image and it would not display in my viewer either. Then I changed `stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor"` to `stroke="black" fill="black"` and I can see it now.
=> there is a bug with the `currentColor` value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem today and I finally found the issue. The equations generated by mathML on Wikipedia use the default color for text with a transparent background. If the default text color is white, you can't see the text because Wikipedia background color is also white.

To fix this, **you must change the default text color to black**.

see: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use#w_change-font-color

Try to unset "use system colors", because some dark themes use white text as default. Set the text color to black and the background color to white.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I actually set the default color in my system to be white (or very close to it) since I use a dark theme. I've never had any problem before so I assumed  it wasn't the issue. 
Again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This answer couldn't solve the same issue of mine. The following link did, though: https://superuser.com/a/1280931/989924